# Are anti-influenza drugs containing pseudoephedrine legal in Georgia?

Tags: air-travel, health, legal, georgia-country

Are the drugs against influenza, that contains **[pseudoephedrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoephedrine)**, legal in Georgia? Can I put them into my travel first-aid kit when traveling by plane?

This drugs have worked very well for me when I've caught influenza in mountains, but I know that pseudoephedrine has effects similar to amphetamine and therefore can be treated as narcotic in some countries...

Comment: It's not so much that it has effects similar to amphetamines, as it is that Pseudo is a key ingredient in the *manufacture* of Methamphetamine.

Comment: It's not a narcotic (painkillers are) but it is restricted to buy it. I am not aware of anywhere that objects to you owning or carrying it. You may find it easier to buy with acetominophen/paracetamol (tylenol) already in it - this is sold with much less restriction because it can't be made into meth. Also see http://news.yahoo.com/better-living-chemistry-making-sudafed-meth-172900896.html for a non-serious tip on getting pseudoephedrine when you need it

Comment: btw. pseudoephedrine is not "anti-influenza" drug, it's  a decongestant used in treatment for common cold and most in anti-allergic medicines. And unless you're planning to pack 100 packages, it won't even look remotely suspicious.

Comment: My preferred decongestants containe pseudoephedrine so when I caught a cold in Georgia and still needed to function, [I tried to buy some](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3325/how-to-find-night-and-day-decongestant-for-a-head-cold-when-theres-a-language?rq=1). The pharmacist looked a bit shocked and said "but that's a narcotic". So you definitely can't buy it there - whether you can take your own with you I would say officially probably not but Georgian customs is a breeze for tourists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, can't find any official information in English or Russian.
All I can say:

1. [According the customs rules](http://georgia.visahq.com/customs/) you are not allowed to import any narcotics and medical drugs containing narcotics.
2. [Here](http://beta.newsgeorgia.ru/incidents/20121107/215318698.html) (link is in Russian) is information about arrests for the holding `Guaifenesin+Pseudoephedrine` drugs, and it is definitely because of **Pseudoephedrine**. So this type of drugs definitely has some serious restrictions in Georgia.

Some forums are saying that you can import such drugs if you have a receipt from your doctor, but I can't guarantee that this is true information.

**So, if I were you, I wouldn't take such drugs for the trip.**